# mysql get row values using group by

Tags: php, mysql

```
id order_id coupon_code coupon_amount
1   100        abc123    50
2   101        abc123    50
3   102        bca412    100
```

and my query is

```
 SELECT `coupon_code`, `order_id`, 
        SUM(`coupon_amount`) AS `total`, 
        COUNT(`id`) as `totRow` 
 FROM `orders` 
 WHERE `coupon_code`!='' 
 GROUP BY `coupon_code`
```

and my output should be

```
coupon code  Usage  Total  Order Id(s)
abc123         2    100    100, 101
bca412         1    100    102
```

How to get all order ids separated by comma in single query?

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT order_id) as order_ids, ...`

Comment: I do not know about the MySQL, but in oracle it can be done with LISTAGG, if it helps : http://tech.pranavmaniar.in/oracle-aggregate-string-into-csv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```sql
SELECT `coupon_code`, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(`order_id`) as order_ids, 
       SUM(`coupon_amount`) AS `total`, 
       COUNT(`id`) as `totRow` 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE `coupon_code`!='' 
GROUP BY `coupon_code`
```